# Declare two custom blocks.

Tags: magento, block

I know that in order to create a new custom block we have to add this part to the config.xml file:

```
<blocks>
        <products1>
            <class>Company_Namespace_Block</class>
        </products1>
</blocks>
```

This goes for creating a single custom block.

But what if I want to create more than one custom blocks. How should I declare them then? Something like this?

```
<blocks>
        <products1>
            <class>Company_Namespace_Block</class>
        </products1>
        <products2>
            <class>Company_Namespace_Block</class>
        </products2>
</blocks>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<blocks>
        <products1>
            <class>Company_Namespace_Block</class>
        </products1>
</blocks>
```

The above is:

- Namespace for all of your Module's block classes.
- Area where all of your block classes will reside.
  **(app/code/{*codePool*}/Company/Namespace/Block)**.
- A sort of Prefix for all Block classes of your module (like
  Company_Namespace_Block_Test, Company_Namespace_Block_Test2)

So, you don't need to replicate the block configuration, to declare more than one block classes. You can declare as many block classes under    **(app/code/{*codePool*}/Company/Namespace/Block)**.